# How to remove unicode when reading data?

Tags: python-2.7, unicode, utf-8, apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following line of Python code:

```
trans = data.map(lambda line: line.strip().split())
```

That produces Unicode strings , for example :

```
u'Hello',u'word'
```

I'd like to get normal UTF-8 or ASCII strings

```
'Hello','word'
```

I tried to convert string to UTF-8 such as

```
trans = data.map(lambda line: line.strip().split().encode("utf-8"))
```

or

```
trans = data.map(lambda line: line.strip().split().encode('ascii','ignore'))
```

But that gives an error :

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Can anybody tell me how I can do this?

**UPDATE :**

data is scv file ,
   trans is RDD

Comment: *Why* do you want to avoid Unicode? It should be the preferred, sane default for most use cases. This smacks of an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: I try to avoid unicode for presentation purposes

Comment: @Toren that makes no sense. Your question shows you trying to encode to UTF-8, which is an encoding of **Unicode**. It still sounds like an XY problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not simply encode and split:

```
data = sc.textFile("README.md")
trans = data.map(lambda x: x.encode("ascii", "ignore").split())
trans.first()
## ['#', 'Apache', 'Spark']
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
ascii = data.map(str)
```

This will convert every element in `data` from `unicode` to `str` by running `str(element)` on each element.

Comment: @zero323, the map I am using is python's built-in map, its different, but that could be more appropriate one, src of rdd.py - https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/rdd.py#L280

Comment: I know but it won't work here, trust me :) RDDs are not iterable.

Comment: I see, that's your answer then :)

Answer (score 1):

Your mapping function is returning a list of unicodes, so you can just use a list comprehension to iterate through these and convert them to strings.

```
trans = data.map(lambda line: [str(word) for word in line.strip().split()])
```